# Foreach of DropDownList html helper with value from the foreach itself

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I'm just inquisitive if this is possible. If so, please help me.

Everything is already set and valid like the:

-Model.info:

```
public class info{
    public string information{get;set;}
}
```

-ViewBag.Infos:

```
ViewBag.Infos = new SelectList(new []{"Option1","Option2"});
```

-I am not finding or encountering an error.

So it goes like this:

```
@foreach(var nom in Model.info)
{
    @Html.DropDownList("Infos",new{@Value = "nom.information"})
}
```

Is it possible to put the `foreach` value of `nom` into each dropdownlist's value?

Answer (score 0):

First error is that you are iterating over Model.info that is an string (is an iteration over every char, the type of nom would be char).

By the other hand, you must define a DropDownList with the ViewBag elements, something like that:

```
@Html.DropDownList("info", ViewBag.info, null, Model.info)
```

Comment: The DropDownList actually works as it's supposed to. I am also not looking for answers for an error. I just want it that each of the generated DropDownList will have the value of ``nom.information`` from ``foreach(var nom in Model.info)``